# Accept/Deny for file transfer in Chat clients

Tags: java, file-upload, user-interface, chat

I plan to introduce file transfer support in the chat widget on my website, and have been wondering why do most chat clients allow transfer only when the receiver acknowledges the same through an "Accept" or "Deny" option?

I am assuming 99% times (if not more) the receiver would be accepting the tramsfer, rather than rejecting it.

Please let me know any thoughts around this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is just good common sense.  Even if 99% of the time the receiver is expecting a file and clicks the Accept, this protects your users from that 1% where someone is trying to dump spam/porn/cruft/viruses/etc onto their machine.

That being said, you can certainly make things easier based on the 99% assumption.  You can make the Accept button be the default when they are prompted. You can add an 'Always accept from this user' option to make thing easier once there is a trust relationship set up.  But in general, just auto-accepting is a dangerous idea.

Comment: and how would the user identify such potential attacks (given that the filename may not indicate so)?

Comment: I think that again it would come down to a trust of who they are chatting with.  Not knowing the context around your chat client I can only speculate, but in general just knowing that a file is coming in, the user can be a little more aware and take appropriate action such as where they save it, closely examining the file once it is downloaded, etc.

Comment: "...once it is downloaded" - that is exactly what I think, which therefore defeats the accept/deny purpose upfront to some extent. Just adds another click, it seems.